# Compiling under Rcpp11 fails, cannot find 'future'

Tags: c++, r, rcpp, rcpp11

I'm attempting to compile an R package using the Rcpp11 bindings to use a C++11 binary under the hood. I have successfully compiled and used this package on my Mac (OSX 10.9.5, the compiler is clang++):

`Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.51) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0
Thread model: posix`

However, an attempt to compile under  64-bit Red Hat Linux with the g++ compiler version 4.4.7-4 fails because the header or library or namespace called `future` cannot be found:

`In file included from RcppExports.cpp:4:
/path/to/R-libs/3.1/Rcpp11/include/Rcpp.h:50:18: error: future: No such file or directory`

As far as I know, `future` is part of the C++11 specification. I find it odd that several other namespaces are successfully loaded (we successfully make it to the 50th line of [Rcpp.h](https://github.com/Rcpp11/Rcpp11/blob/master/inst/include/Rcpp.h)), but `future` doesn't. Is this due to using an outdated compiler? For reference, I'll attach the actual call to the g++ compiler that fails:

`g++ -m64 -std=c++0x -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include -I"/path/to/R-libs/3.1/Rcpp11/include"   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o`

Comment: Yes, g++ 4.4.* is (way) too old for any meaningful C++11 work, and it won't matter which Rcpp* variant you use as the constraint comes from the C++11 side.  With an old Rd Hat box you will have difficulties no matter what.

Comment: Technically, 4.4.7 isn't that old, but of course 4.4.0 was released on April 19th 2009, so the main release is a bit over 5 years old by now. It was released on March 13th 2012. gcc 4.7.0 is the first to fully support C++11, which was released on the Marth 22nd 2012. But as RedHat are conservative with new versions, picking a 4.7.0 release over a 4.4.7 is probably a bit risky, as things are likely to change between 4.4 and 4.5, never mind 4.4 to 4.7. I personally would get 4.8.2 or 4.9.1, build that locally and go for it.

Comment: Thanks, guys. Sadly, this Red Hat box is my department's high performance server, and I don't have root access to install a newer compiler. Sigh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `Rcpp11` does not compile, it usually means that the compiler is not a C++11 compiler. Previous versions of `Rcpp11` used some compromise on what `C++11` means, but the next versions won't compromise. `C++11` = `C++11`, not unfinished `C++0x`.

What makes `C++11` and forward great is how all these pieces fit together.

Having a `C++11` compiler is the price to pay to use `Rcpp11`. I see this as a feature.